# 'override' can only be specified on class members 2

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

My build is failing when I try to run, here is the whole code. The error is on the last two override functions.

When I fix the error through Xcode's suggested correction (removing 'override') the build still fails.

Any help? Here is the code copied and pasted;

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var age: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func findAge(sender: AnyObject) {

        var enteredAge = age.text.toInt()

        if enteredAge != nil {

        var catYears = enteredAge! * 7

        resultLabel.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) in cat years"

        } else {

            resultLabel.text = "please enter number in box"

   }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

Comment: You are missing a closing curly brace `}`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: I've added a closing curly brace, yet the build still fails

Comment: The missing one is after `"please enter number in box"` string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to add a closing } for your func findAge.

Answer (score -1):

xCode is a bit buggy...
heres what i did...
put a new 
}
just above the override func
then delete it
it just works...or for me at least..